# How to analyze and understand the expression "embodying and imagining community together" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions, sentence-structure

I came across a long sentence in today's NYT.

[>...reminding us that theater and performance are powerful resources for **embodying and imagining community together**.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/22/theater/hamilton-and-history.html)

I find it an ambiguous expression by using the word "together" here. Here are my questions,

1. Does it refer to "powerful resources together" ,"both embodying community and imagining community"or "community together"?
2. What does "embody and imagine community" mean?
3. I can't grasp the accurate meaning of the sentence. What does the whole sentence mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this quote, "together" refers to society and all of its members.  You could rewrite it as:

> ...reminding us that theater and performance are powerful resources for *all of us in American society* to embody and imagine community together.

Once you rephrase it as such, then "embody" and "imagine" should be understood as their regular dictionary definitions.  "All of us in American society embody community" = we all are members of the community.  "All of us in American society imagine community" = we all can envision a better community in the future.